# 2023 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2023 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://robotics.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 4):

Although I have been a pro-tem moderator of Robotics since its inception, I will not be standing in this election... other commitments mean I no longer have the time to be as active as needed, and this election is the ideal time to step back.

Robotics is my only experience of being a SE moderator - it has a great group of contributors, and I'm grateful for the support, camaraderie and teamwork of the other moderators past and present.

It has been an honour and a privilege... thanks all.

Comment: Thanks for all of the hard work you've put in over the years Andrew, it was pleasure working with you.

Answer (score 2):

I put in an application, but I was wondering if Tully would as well. I was assuming Mark and Ben would both stay on. There are only three positions available, so when I saw that Tully did indeed put in an application I withdrew mine so there are no conflicts.

I had advocated for ROS at my previous employer, around 2015 or so, but couldn't overcome the institutional inertia to get things moving then. I since changed jobs and I've been using ROS daily for about 2 years now, and I'm really honored and excited to have Tully on board here and want to do everything I can to continue to grow our relationship with the ROS community and to hopefully have that drive more traffic to this site. I'm hoping my stepping aside guarantees Tully a moderator position, that his new position encourages even more interaction here, and that the interaction ultimately that grows the community <3

Love you guys, happy to see everyone applying :)

Comment: Copying my comment here from the election chat room: "There actually *needs* to be at least 1 more applicant than the number of open moderator slots in order for the election to be competitive, which is necessary to move on to the Voting phase. (And for the graduation election and any future elections, elections are required to be competitive; if such an election isn't, the election will fail.)"

Comment: (Note: The nomination period will automatically be extended by 1 week if there isn't at least 1 more nomination by 20:00 UTC – which is a little under 3 hours from now.)